# How to auth from production nodejs server to get token for google spreadsheets API

Tags: node.js, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

i've implemented Google Spreadsheets API in an nodejs server, on localhost first time it asked to go to some specific url and copy token, i did this and everything was fine.

But on PROD, i see that it asks for the same thing, but i can't do that for PROD server ( i mean that i can't open console like on local machine and insert that code generated by google ).

So, what can i do? How can i make it works for PROD server.

P.S i've already tried with API keys, but it expects OAuth 2 access token.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean. Could you post some code?

Generally when using the Google SDK in Node, you have the standard developer token, and you get a user access token from the user's Google account - whether that's you or anyone else. You can set those in your environment such as a .env file or in your app's settings on something like Heroku. There's no need for a console.